# How to set Startup object of a class from developers console when we have more than one main method in the project

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

This would be question from c# beginner. I have a console application with 5 classes and a main method in each class, is there a way to set startup object (Main(string[] args)) while executing this application from developers console ? It works fine when i set Startup object in properties of application but i want to set it from command console.

Please help me.

Comment: You using visual studio right?

Comment: Here are instructions for VisualStudio15. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx
Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to set it from developers console not from visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You can compile using specific main functions using the [/main:class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538.aspx) compiler option, but it sounds like you want to choose which main to use after compiling, as the program is initiated(?)

I'm not sure about using multiple mains post compiling, why not just create a single main that directs to whatever class/object you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right and by developers console you mean Windows' Command Prompt, you can do something like:

On Program.cs:

- Inside `void main` add:

  ```
  switch (args[0])  {
    case "method1":
      new ClassWithMainMethod1().Main();
      break;
    case "method2":
      new ClassWithMainMethod2().Main();
      break;
    case "method3":
      new ClassWithMainMethod3().Main();
      break;
    case "method4":
      new ClassWithMainMethod4().Main();
      break;
    case "method5":
      new ClassWithMainMethod5().Main();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  ```

That way, you can launch the different main methods using the Command Prompt like `program.exe methodX` (*methodX* being one of the names you specified on the `switch`)

Comment: If this was perfect for you, why did you not mark this as an answer?